# Can't get AddExplosionForce to work with children of game object

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a game object that has several children. I am trying to detach the children from the parent, and apply explosive force to each one based on the location on the parent. The children detach just fine, and the parent is removed (I checked the scene while the game was running) I checked which of the game objects that are close to the explosion position, and they print out ok. I just can't get the explosive force to work on them. Each of the children has a Rigidbody (set in the prefab), and I added a box collider in code. I tried a larger blast radius, but that didn't help either.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    for(int i=0;i<transform.childCount;)
    {
        Transform childTransform = transform.GetChild(0);
        Debug.Log("C"+childTransform.transform.position);
        childTransform.parent = null;
        childTransform.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(pos, 10);
    foreach (Collider childGameObject in colliders)
    {
        Debug.Log(childGameObject.name);
        childGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(10f, pos, 10f, 10f);
        //childGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce(300f, pos, 300f, 10f);
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out.  I needed to add the ForceMode to get the explosion that I was looking for.  I ended up using ForceMode.Impulse, and it worked really well.

Comment: don't comments on answer section...